# Laravel Blade: Getting access to a variable in a nested partial from a parent view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My parent view looks like this:
**show.blade.php**

```
@include('inquiries.partials.inquiries')
```

It uses the following partial:
**inquiries.blade.php**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($inquiry as $key => $item)
        <li>
            @include('inquiries.partials.inquiry')
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Which uses another partial:
**inquiry.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="data"> ... </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
         @yield('inquiry.toolbar', '')
    </div>
</div>
```

In **show.blade.php** I want to define **inquiry.toolbar** section for **inquiry.blade.php**, however I need to access **$key** variable from **inquiries.blade.php** file, like so:

```
@include('inquiries.partials.inquiries')

@section('inquiry.toolbar')
{!! button_delete([
    'route' => ['inquiries.items.destroy', $key]
]) !!}
@stop
```

However, the code above does not work (I get "Undefined variable: key").

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass data when including a view, like so:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($inquiry as $key => $item)
        <li>
            @include('inquiries.partials.inquiry', compact('key'))
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

And it will be available on your view.

Check [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates) for more information.

Comment: This passes the variable to a sub-view. However I want to overwrite section in the parent view using data passed to a sub-view.

Comment: @Mike In this case you should check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19384105/804741). You can use `view()->share()` on your controller to make a variable (like `$inquiry`) available on all your views. It might not be exactly how you want, but it works.